# Optimization with parametric constraints: solution maps

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

For constrained optimization problems

$$ \begin{array}{ll} \min\limits_{x \in \mathbb R^n} & f(p, x) \\
\text{s.t.} & x \in C \end{array} $$

where $p \in \mathbb R$ is a parameter, we can deduce, under convexity of $f, C$, existence and Lipschitzness (in $p$) of solution maps $x^*(p) \in \arg\min\limits_{x \in C} f(p, x)$, say, by applying Theorem 2F.10 from this [Rockafellar's book](https://books.google.de/books?hl=en&lr=&id=JSREAAAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&ots=wJcJdJ-n1Y&sig=LWUmYfxUMKj8Z5KvoyrxAoqkCUs&redir_esc=y#v=snippet&q=2f.10&f=false). Here, I attached an excerpt from there:

[image: Theorem 2F.10]

---

**Question**: under what conditions Lipschitz-dependence of the solution map can be derived when $C$ depends on $p$? Say, if it's described by $g(p, x) \le 0$ with whatever properties required, like continuity in $p, x$, (strong) convexity in $x$ for each $p$ etc.

The said book does not seem to contain a result in such a generic form.

One particular problem I see there is that the subgradients be pivoted to the static constraint. The argument collapses when the constraint changes

---

I'm almost sure that if the cost function is convex and the constraint doesn't change arbitrarily fast, the optimum must be continuous with a bounded rate of change

---

This is a repost of [my MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3577531/optimization-with-parametric-constraints-solution-maps) that, unfortunately, didn't lead anywhere, so I decided to try my luck here.

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly. Lets stay one-dimensional and take $f(x)=-x^2$ and $C(p)=[p-1,p+1]$ then $argmin_{x \in C(p)} f(x)=p+sign(p)$. So even though $f$ and $C$ are smooth in $x$ and $p$ the solution map is not. Doesn't this show that it is impossible allow $C$ to depend on $p$ while still have smoothness of the solution map?

Comment: @user35593 I specified the question better. It should be possible to achieve to continuity and even Lipschitzness when $f,g$ are convex and $g$ depends on $p$ continuously

Comment: I came up with the following counterexample to show that continuity or convexity in x for each p is not enough. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ resp. $g: \mathbb{R}^2\times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x)=x_1^2$ resp. $g(x,p)=(x_1-px_2)^2-1$. Then the minimizer is $x^*=(0,1/p)$ for $p\neq 0$. Hence it is not continuous at zero.

Comment: @user35593 But $g$ is not convex in $x$ for every $p$

Comment: it is not strictly convex but it is convex. I actually meant $g(x,p)=(x_1-2-px_2)^2-1$ so that $C$ does not contain the global minimum of $f$.